# RegExp to split string according to different criteria in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to split string using regex.

for ex.

```
when [python] or [html ] demo  "css html"   -[javascript] score:5
```

from this string i want, following lists,

```
contains = ['when', 'demo']
word_press = ["css html"]
tags = ['python', 'or', 'html', '-', 'javascript']
options = [{score:5}]
```

- all the word enclosed in `"[]"`(bracket) will be tag list.
- word between this `""` will be in word_press list.
- word that has `:` in word it will be in options list.
- other then above criteria will be in contains list.

i tried this,

```
((?:or\s|-)?\[.*?\])|(".*?")|([a-z]+:\d*)|(\S+)
```

[live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/jX4eR2/2)

it work fine, but i use it with python

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''[python] or [html] how to "how to" user:2525
... [demo] how to createscore:5
... when [python] or [html] demo  "css html"   -[javascript] score:5'''
>>> re.findall('''((?:or\s|-)?\[.*?\])|(".*?")|([a-z]+:\d*)|(\S+)''', s)
[('[python]', '', '', ''),
 ('or [html]', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'how'),
 ('', '', '', 'to'),
 ('', '"how to"', '', ''),
 ('', '', 'user:2525', ''),
 ('[demo]', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'how'),
 ('', '', '', 'to'),
 ('', '', 'createscore:5', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'when'),
 ('[python]', '', '', ''),
 ('or [html]', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'demo'),
 ('', '"css html"', '', ''),
 ('-[javascript]', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', 'score:5', '')]
```

it return tuple in list. is there a way to fetch groups like

```
group1 = ['[python]', 'or [html]', '[demo]', '[python]', 'or [html]', '-[javascript]']
...
```

Comment: in what basis you're trying to split like the above?

Comment: Why is `or` a "tag"?

Comment: `split string according to different criteria using python`, could you explain the criteria?

Comment: Instead of using a single regex I'd use a scanner. There is an *undocumented* `Scanner` class in the `re` module that makes it  very simple to write such a scanner.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Because *gimme teh code* questions are welcome on SO. And he added the regex only now, not when he first opened the question

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/dA2dF4/1)? It would be helpful if you were much clearer about your criteria.

Comment: @LutzHorn i update my question what i want...thanks!!

Comment: @jonrsharpe ya i want same that you suggest can u give a example in python in more detail ..thanks!!

Comment: @i'mPosSible ...that *is* in Python, it's using Python's regex syntax. It also provides a detailed explanation and colourful highlighting, so I'm not sure what more detail you want. SO isn't a regex-writing service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe your solution is work for me, please post as answer it. i accept it and useful to other. thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''[python] or [html] how to "how to" user:2525
[demo] how to createscore:5
when [python] or [html] demo  "css html"   -[javascript] score:5'''
```

Here is one possible regular expression (including inline comments) for capturing the information you need (see demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dA2dF4/1)):

```
>>> pattern = r'''
    (?P<tag>                 # define group one - tags
    (?:or\s|-)?              # - acceptable words/chars for preceding tags
    \[.*?\])                 # - tag definition - words in square brackets
    |(?P<word_press>".*?")   # group two - words in quotes
    |(?P<options>[a-z]+:\d*) # group three - options with colons
    |(?P<other>\S+)          # group four - anything left over
'''
```

Note that using this with `findall` will give you a list of tuples:

```
>>> re.findall(pattern, s, re.VERBOSE)
[('[python]', '', '', ''),
 ('or [html]', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'how'), 
 ('', '', '', 'to'),
 ('', '"how to"', '', ''),
 ('', '', 'user:2525', ''), 
 ('[demo]', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'how'),
 ('', '', '', 'to'), 
 ('', '', 'createscore:5', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'when'),
 ('[python]', '', '', ''), 
 ('or [html]', '', '', ''), 
 ('', '', '', 'demo'), 
 ('', '"css html"', '', ''), 
 ('-[javascript]', '', '', ''), 
 ('', '', 'score:5', '')]
```

But here is a functional-programming way to rearrange it:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> map(partial(filter, None), zip(*re.findall(pattern, s, re.VERBOSE)))
[('[python]', 'or [html]', '[demo]', '[python]', 'or [html]', '-[javascript]'), 
 ('"how to"', '"css html"'), 
 ('user:2525', 'createscore:5', 'score:5'), 
 ('how', 'to', 'how', 'to', 'when', 'demo')]
```

Comment: there is possible to read tule using group ?? like `match.group('tag')` it return tag list ??